# cbind data without specifying inputs

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have a piece of code, I want to cbind my data. The catch is I will not always have eighta data files to cbind. I would like to keep the code below and import just five, if I have five.
The reason is this. I will will always have between 1 - 100 dataframes to cbind, I dont want always manually tell R to cbind one or 100. I want to just have cbind (1 :100) and always cbind what needs to be cbind.

```
finaltable<- cbind(onea, twoa, threea, foura, fivea, sixa, sevena, eighta)
```

Comment: You may look at `do.call(cbind, list(...))` where `list` is a list of your data. So just load your data from files in a list of data.frames or matrices and apply `do.call` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more data, here's a contrived example. First, I'll make some example files with the same number of rows in each:

```
filenames <- paste0(c('onea', 'twoa', 'threea', 'foura'), '.csv')
for (fn in filenames)
    write.csv(matrix(runif(5), nc = 1), file = fn, row.names = FALSE)
```

Let's first dynamically derive a list of filenames to process. (This code is assuming that the previous lines making these files did not happen.)

```
(filenames <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv'))
##  [1] "foura.csv"  "onea.csv"   "threea.csv" "twoa.csv"
```

This is the "hard" part, reading the files:

```
(ret <- do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames,
                              function(fn) read.csv(fn, header = TRUE))))
##           V1        V1        V1        V1
##  1 0.9091705 0.4934781 0.7607488 0.4267438
##  2 0.9692987 0.4349523 0.6066990 0.9134305
##  3 0.6444404 0.8639983 0.1473830 0.9844336
##  4 0.7719652 0.1492200 0.7731319 0.9689941
##  5 0.9237107 0.6317367 0.2565866 0.1084299
```

For proof of concept, here's the same thing but operating on a subset of the vector of filenames, showing that the length of the vector is not a concern:

```
(ret <- do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames[1:2],
                              function(fn) read.csv(fn, header = TRUE))))
##           V1        V1
##  1 0.9091705 0.4934781
##  2 0.9692987 0.4349523
##  3 0.6444404 0.8639983
##  4 0.7719652 0.1492200
##  5 0.9237107 0.6317367
```

You may want/need to redefine the names of the columns (with `names(ret) <- filenames`, for example), but you can always reference the columns by numbered indexing (e.g., `ret[,2]`) without worrying about names.

Comment: Well, I am reading in files this way:  ###### checks all files in directory ########
readinfiles<-function(){
 details<- file.info(list.files("file path", all.files=F, full.name=T));
 details<- details[with(details, order(as.POSIXct(mtime))),]
 file<- rownames(details)
}
all_files<- readinfiles();
list_all_files<- as.list(all_files);
list_all_files;

Comment: one<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[1]), header=T);
two<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[2]), header=T);
three<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[3]), header=T);
four<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[4]), header=T);
five<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[5]), header=T);
six<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[6]), header=T);
seven<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[7]), header=T);
eight<- read.table(as.character(list_all_files[8]), header=T);Then I am taking this list and individually putting into this format:

Comment: I am then cbinding the above, I need a way that I can say cbind all these files without knowing how many is there.

Comment: @Chad, the only changes to my code would be replace my variable `filenames` with your `list_all_files` and replace `read.csv` with `read.table`. Your list is already sorted in the correct order based on your `readinfiles()` function. My `ret` variable will contain one column per file -- in increasing order of file modification time. Have you tried my code?

Comment: @ r2evans, this is what I have:      ret <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list_all_files[1:length(list_all_files)],
+                               function(fn) read.table(fn, header = TRUE)))

Comment: The use of `1:length(list_all_files)` is redundant here. You're using `rbind` here in place of `cbind`, is that intentional? (It is not what you were asking in the OP.)

Comment: @ r2evans, it is rbind not cbind, they both work either way. Using this filenames[1:2], only gives the first two data sets to read in, but if I used 1:length(list_all_files), it read in everything.

Comment: @ r2evans, you have been very helpful, and reduced 60 lines of code into just a few lines.

Comment: The use of `filenames[1:2]` was merely (as I said in the answer) a demonstration that it worked equally well on lists of different lengths; it was a proof of concept only. All you're doing when you say `[1:length(list_all_files)]` is "please use all elements" which is the default when you do not subset it at all.

Comment: this makes sense, you are correct in the above statement. Thanks.